# Invalid storage account when developing Azure Function in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-storage, azure-functions

I'm developing Azure Function in Visual Studio using C#. And I'n running it locally on my development machine which sits behind a proxy. However keep getting this error:

`Exception binding parameter Invalid storage account Please make sure your credentials are correct`

In my C# class I have following function which have an output binding to a Service Bus queue.

```
[FunctionName("MyTestFunction")]        
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, [Queue("myqueue")]IAsyncCollector<string> myQueue, TraceWriter log)
```

In local.settings.json, I populated AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard with connection string copied from Azure Storage Explorer

```
{    
  "IsEncrypted": false,  
  "Values": {"AzureWebJobsStorage":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountname;AccountKey=sNFYlzkTtIVejJqU36rhByzDq91Nyv+JQ==;BlobEndpoint=https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://storageaccount.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://storageaccount.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://storageaccount.file.core.windows.net/;",
"AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storageaccountname;AccountKey=sNFYlzkTtIVejJqU36rhByzDq91Nyv+JQ==;BlobEndpoint=https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://storageaccount.queue.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://storageaccount.table.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://storageaccount.file.core.windows.net/;"
  }
}
```

It worked for me for a while, but then stopped working all together. I triple checked everything and still couldn't figure out what I did wrong. Can someone point me to the right direction for this please?

The value I have for AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard are straight copy from the Primary Connection String of my storage account in Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: It looks like we throw that exception explicitly if we think the password is incorrect. Are you able to use that same key in another application -- such as [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) -- and connect successfully?

Comment: Yes. Azure Storage Explorer connect fine, that how I manage to copy the Primary Connection String from there. I should also mention, I'm running this on my local machine and it is behind a proxy.

Comment: Some other things to try: Another account? Try outside the proxy? Try deploying to Azure and see if it works? If it's not the password, it'll help to isolate where it's breaking.

Comment: brettsam, apart from setting the correct Connection String in AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard, what else I need to setup to have my solution correctly authenticated against Azure? I've tried another storage account, have the exactly same problem. It would take some efforts to get it tested outside the proxy which something I will try over the weekend.

Comment: Manage to move my solution to machine with direct internet connection. The problem gone away straightaway. I can conclude it is a proxy issue. My question now is how do I properly set the proxy for this to work?

Comment: Run Azure Storage Emulator if it’s not running

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error message:

> Missing storage secret credentials.

Following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local), I used the Azure Functions CLI (func.exe) (Command Line Interface) to update all necessary credentials in my `local.settings.json`.

1. Ensure you have node.js
2. Install Azure CLI if not already done so: `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools`
3. In your Azure Functions v2 project root directory, execute `func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings myawesomefunctionappname`
4. You should see your credentials getting updated in `local.settings.js`. Local debugging might require you to have non-encrypted credentials. Simply set `IsEncrypted: false` in that file.

Here's a sample:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "...",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~2",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "...",
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION": "8.11.1",
    "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES": "*",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "1"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those experiencing the same problem - developing Azure Functions locally (using Visual Studio) behind a proxy.

Here is how I fixed the issue - adding proxy settings in the func.exe.Config. You will be able to find the file under `C:\Users\{yourAccountName}\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.0\func.exe.Config`

Add your proxy settings as:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy usesystemdefault="True" proxyaddress="http://my.proxy.com:8080" bypassonlocal="True" autoDetect="True" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Hope this helps someone.

I really wish the error message returned actually tells us the CLI is actually not able to connect to Azure, rather than keep telling me I'm using an invalid storage account.

Answer (score 0):

We were recently facing a similar issue with one of our web job which was working fine earlier but suddenly stopped working. Web job tried to restart every minute but it was getting failed with the error message **Invalid storage account *ABStorage*. Please make sure your credentials are correct.** Web job remained in Pending Restart status. Upon investigation, we found out that the storage connection string is perfectly fine while there is some bug in Azure storage SDK due to which CORS rules configured on Azure portal against the storage account were not being interpreted correctly. In the Azure portal, we had only 1 CORS rule on Azure storage having all allowed HTTP methods selected. We updated the CORS rule on the storage account to have one HTTP method per domain and the web job was able to start immediately.
[image: Multiple HTTP methods in one row]
[image: One HTTP method per row]