# Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureCosmosDBConnection' is invalid

Tags: java, azure, function, azure-functions

I have this problen when I try to run a function with BlobTrigger.

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.myFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage:
Storage account connection string for 'AzureWebJobsAzureCosmosDBConnection' is invalid.
```

The variables are:

```json
AzureWebJobsAzureCosmosDBConnection = AccountEndpoint=https://example.com/;AccountKey=YYYYYYYYYYY;

AzureWebJobsStorage = UseDevelopmentStorage=true

AzureCosmosDBConnection = AccountEndpoint=https://example.com/;AccountKey=YYYYYYYYYYY;
```

I don't know why this function throws exception....

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure, if you have written your `local.settings.json` configuration will be in the format of `key = value` or just mentioned in the question.
The format of `local.settings.json` configuration to any Azure Function will be `"key":"value"`:

[image]

```json
{

"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=pravustorageac88;AccountKey=<alpha-numeric-symbolic_access_key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
"MAIN_CLASS":"com.example.DemoApplication",
"AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=pravustorageac88;AccountKey=<alpha-numeric-symbolic_access_key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
"AzureCosmosdBConnStr":"Cosmos_db_conn_str"
}
}
```

If you are using Cosmos DB Connection string, then you have to configure in such a way:

```java
public  HttpResponseMessage  execute(
@HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST}, authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
@CosmosDBOutput(name="database", databaseName = "db_name", collectionName = "collection_name", connectionStringSetting = "AzureCosmosDBConnection")
ExecutionContext  context)
```

Make Sure the cosmos database connection string present in the `local.settigns.json` file should be published to Azure Function App Configuration Menu > Application Settings.
For that either uncomment `local.settings.json` from `.gitignore` file or add the configuration settings manually to the Azure Function App Configuration:

[image]

I have uncommented the `local.settings.json` in `.gitignore` file and then published to Azure Function App as the cosmos database connection string also updated in the configuration:

[image]

**Note**:

1. *If you have a proxy in the system, then you have to add the proxy settings in `func.exe` configuration file, given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394678) by @*p31415926**
2. *In two of the ways, you can configure the Cosmos DB Connection in the Azure Function Java Stack: [Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2?tabs=in-process,extensionv4&pivots=programming-language-java) (as code given above) and using the SDK given in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=in-process,functionsv2&pivots=programming-language-java).*

Comment: In my case I use @BlobTrigger